# String to array with IFS in bash 4 not working like it does in bash 3

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that contains `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a codeLangArray <<<"$codeLangList"` in order to create an array from a string with multiple lines, delineated by new lines.

Eg.

```
codeLangList="
PHP
Go
Java
Javascript"
```

This seems to work in Bash 3, but when I run it in Bash 4 it just hangs.

Comment: What's a typical or sample value of `codeLangList`?

Comment: In `bash` 4, you should use `readarray -t codeLangArray <<< "$codeLangList"` anyway.

Comment: It works for me, in both bash 4.4.12(1)-release under NetBSD, and 4.2.10(1)-release under macOS. I think there's something else going on in your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help @chepner and @gordon-davisson. I was indeed because of something else in my environment, I have `set -e` at the top of my Bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase I had `set -e` at the top of my Bash file the script was exiting. I guess it though the `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a codeLangArray <<<"$codeLangList"` line was failing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It was failing; `read -d ''` prevents `read` from interpreting any value in the input as terminating a line, so that then entire input is read. However, *because* it never finds a line terminator, it has an exit status of 1, which triggers `set -e`. So you can see both why `read -d ''` is a hack (albeit a necessary one prior to `bash` 4), and how `set -e` cannot distinguish between errors and failures.

Comment: One workaround for `bash` 3 would be `read ... || true`, which forces the overall command to succeed, preventing `set -e`-based termination.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @chepner. That makes things much clearer for me.